# Ethereum geth node sync problem

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, cryptography, fast-sync

I have to ethereum geth node runing as testnet syncmode=full on aws  both running on same hardware and bandwidth why one is syncing very slow and other one is syncing fast?

and if I will stop the geth via ctrl+c and start again it stating sync faster.

What's the reason actually behind?

Comment: what block number are you currently on?

Comment: It's near 900000

Comment: Do you have a sample of the output of each node? How long they are running? Is the block difference between nodes very large or small? The most common problem with syncing today is storage, perhaps the 'hardware' is not the identical between them.